# LINQ Lambda grouping into nested lists

Tags: .net, linq, lambda

Hi i have data in list

```
ID | val1 | val2 | val3
1  | a    | b    | c
1  | c    | d    | e
2  | a    | b    | c
2  | d    | z    | g
3  | a    | b    | c
```

And I want to transform into list with nested list like:

```
ID 1 (2 elements in nested list)
ID 2 (2 elements in nested list)
ID 3 (1 element in nested list)
```

Using lanbda I want to fit data from example 1 into:

```
List<object>; 
class object  { 
int ID; 
Class List<details> }
Class details{
int val1;
int val2;
int val3;}
```

Comment: Great! Do you have a problem in your implementation? Please add [mcve] of your code and explain what is the problem

Comment: Yes... have no idea how to implement this. My code is much more complex, so i distil it to bare problem. I'm trying to fit data from DB into the object: List<object> ; class object {int ID; Class List<details>}

Answer (score 1):

This is the general gist of it.

```
var list = new List<Data>()
{
    new Data(){ ID = 1, Val1 = "a", Val2 = "b", Val3 = "c" },
    new Data(){ ID = 1, Val1 = "c", Val2 = "d", Val3 = "e" },
    new Data(){ ID = 2, Val1 = "a", Val2 = "b", Val3 = "c" },
    new Data(){ ID = 2, Val1 = "d", Val2 = "z", Val3 = "g" },
    new Data(){ ID = 3, Val1 = "a", Val2 = "b", Val3 = "c" },
};

list.GroupBy(l => l.ID).ToList()
    .ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine($"ID {g.Key} ({g.ToList().Count} elements in nested list)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have an input sequence of objects and you want to group them into groups of objects with the same `ID`. Each group has a List of `Detail` objects, containing the Val1 / Val2 / Val3 of your input sequence that have this ID

Luckily, I don't have to make a function, it already exists. It is called [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var groups = myInputList.GroupBy(
    inputElement => inputElement.Id,
    groupElement => new Detail()
    {
        val1 = groupElement.val1,
        val2 = groupElement.val2,
        val3 = groupElement.val3,
    });
```

What it does, it takes all elements from the input list. From every element in this input list it takes the Id. This is defined by the first parameter:

```
inputElement => inputElement.Id,
```

All inputElements that have the same value for property Id are put in the same group. The second parameter says what you should do with the element in each group:

```
 groupElement => new Detail()
    {
        val1 = groupElement.val1,
        val2 = groupElement.val2,
        val3 = groupElement.val3,
    }
```

It says here: if you have an element that should be put in this group, make a new Detail object, and give the properties the values as described

The result is a sequence of objects that implement IGrouping. This means that every group has a property Key which has your value ID, and it is a sequence of Detail objects, coming from original elements that had this ID (note that I wrote the group IS a sequence, not: HAS a sequence

If you really want it in the format you described you'll have to do a Select after it:

```
.Select(group => new object ()      // why use this horrible name for your type?
{
     Id = group.Key,
     Details = group.ToList(),
})
.ToList();
```

Quite often, you'll use the results immediately after the query. In that case it is better not to convert your original items, only do the GroupBy

```
var groupsWithSameId = myInputList.GroupBy(inputElement => inputElement.Id);

foreach(var group in groupsWithSameId)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Group {group.Key}");
    foreach (var element in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.Val1);
        Console.WriteLine(element.Val2);
        Console.WriteLine(element.Val2);
    }
}
```

See? because I don't do all the projections into other classes it is much simpler to read / test / maintain